# Some Basic Python Questions

Tags: php, python, unicode, replace, html-entities

I'm a total python noob so please bear with me. I want to have python scan a page of html and replace instances of Microsoft Word entities with something UTF-8 compatible.

My question is, how do you do that in Python (I've Googled this but haven't found a clear answer so far)? I want to dip my toe in the Python waters so I figure something simple like this is a good place to start. It seems that I would need to:

1. load text pasted from MS Word into a variable
2. run some sort of replace function on the contents
3. output it

In PHP I would do it like this:

```
$test = $_POST['pasted_from_Word']; //for example “Going Mobile”

function defangWord($string) 
{
    $search = array(
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x98)),
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x99)),
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9c)), 
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x9d)), 
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x93)),
        (chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x94)), 
        (chr(0x2d))
    ); 

    $replace = array(
        "&lsquo;",
        "&rsquo;",
        "&ldquo;",
        "&rdquo;",
        "&ndash;",
        "&mdash;",
        "&ndash;"
    );

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
} 

echo defangWord($test);
```

How would you do it in Python?

EDIT: Hmmm, ok ignore my confusion about UTF-8 and entities for the moment. The input contains text pasted from MS Word. Things like curly quotes are showing up as odd symbols. Various PHP functions I used to try and fix it were not giving me the results I wanted. By viewing those odd symbols in a hex editor I saw that they corresponded to the symbols I used above (0xe2, 0x80 etc.). So I simply swapped out the oddball characters with HTML entities. So if the bit I have above already IS UTF-8, what is being pasted in from MS Word that is causing the odd symbols?

EDIT2: So I set out to learn a bit about Python and found I don't really understand encoding. The problem I was trying to solve can be handled simply by having sonsistent encoding from end to end. If the input form is UTF-8, the database that stores the input is UTF-8 and the page that outputs it is UTF-8... pasting from Word works fine. No special functions needed. Now, about learning a little Python...

Comment: +1: "defangWord()"... I love it! :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, those aren't Microsoft Word entities—they **are** UTF-8.  You're converting them to HTML entities.

The Pythonic way to write something like:

```
chr(0xe2) . chr(0x80) . chr(0x98)
```

would be:

```
'\xe2\x80\x98'
```

But Python already has built-in functionality for the type of conversion you want to do:

```
def defang(string):
    return string.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

This will replace the UTF-8 codes in a string for characters like `‘` with numeric entities like `&#8220;`.

If you want to replace those numeric entities with named ones where possible:

```
import re
from htmlentitydefs import codepoint2name

def convert_match_to_named(match):
    num = int(match.group(1))
    if num in codepoint2name:
        return "&%s;" % codepoint2name[num]
    else:
        return match.group(0)

def defang_named(string):
    return re.sub('&#(\d+);', convert_match_to_named, defang(string))
```

And use it like so:

```
>>> defang_named('\xe2\x80\x9cHello, world!\xe2\x80\x9d')
'&ldquo;Hello, world!&rdquo;'
```

---

To complete the answer, the equivalent code to your example to process a file would look something like this:

```
# in Python, it's common to operate a line at a time on a file instead of
# reading the entire thing into memory

my_file = open("test100.html")
for line in my_file:
    print defang_named(line)
my_file.close()
```

Note that this answer is targeted at Python 2.5; the Unicode situation is dramatically different for Python 3+.

I also agree with bobince's comment below: if you can just keep the text in UTF-8 format and send it with the correct content-type and charset, do that; if you need it to be in ASCII, then stick with the numeric entities—there's really no need to use the named ones.

Comment: +1 for xmlcharrefreplace — there is no need for HTML named entities today really. But really, leave the UTF-8 alone, smart-quotes intact. As long as you serve it with the correct ‘charset’ header/meta-tag there is no problem.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the entities are UTF-8 and not some MS weirdness ;-) (and for a well-written answer overall, too)

Comment: I'm confused. The document I am importing in the example is full of strange symbols that correspond to MS Word curly quotes. If I drop them straight into a page with UTF-8 encoding I get strange symbols. If I convert them using my example code they render fine. So, what are they before I convert?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean when you say "drop them straight into a page with UTF-8 encoding".  It sounds like you're opening the test100.html file in a text editor with the incorrect character set (probably Windows-1252)—make sure you open it as UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. The PHP I wrote was created to handle people pasting directly from Word into a textarea. The pasted code would then appear with the garbled symbols (looking like  â€œInside Quotesâ€ for example) and I could not find a good solution to clean it. My above code cleans it.

Comment: Basically I want to clean text that was input by pasting from Word into a textarea. I shouldn't have used an html page for my example, in reality I was dealing with text input via a form. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does the pasted content appear garbled *immediately* when it is pasted? Or after the form has been posted to the server and redisplayed on the following page?  What you're describing is symptomatic of UTF-8 encoded text being interpreted as Latin-1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: Does the page with the textarea have its charset set to UTF-8? (With the appropriate HTTP Content-Type header, or putting <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> in the <head>)

Comment: No. It appears correct. The pages handling the output are all UTF-8, though, so I suspect it is Windows-1252 that cannot be rendered properly. Maybe? I edited my example above to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: "Does the page with the textarea have its charset set to UTF-8?" Actually it is charset=iso-8859-1 on the input page and it WAS the same on the output page but I changed it to UTF-8 (on the output page). So it is a mess of 1252 being pasted into 8859-1 and viewed on utf-8. Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

The Python code has the same outline.

Just replace all of the PHP-isms with Python-isms.

Start by creating a [File](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) object.  The result of a file.read() is a [string](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) object.  Strings have a "replace" operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for cleaning Word HTML is using [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) which has a mode just for that.  There are [a few Python wrappers](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=tidy&submit=search) you can use if you need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

As S.Lott said, the Python code would be very, very similar—the only differences would essentially be the function calls/statements.

I don't think Python has a direct equivalent to `file_get_contents()`, but since you can obtain an array of the lines in the file, you can then join them by newlines, like this:

```
sample = '\n'.join(open(test, 'r').readlines())
```

EDIT: Never mind, there's a much easier way: `sample = file(test).read()`

String replacing is almost exactly the same as `str_replace()`:

```
sample = sample.replace(search, replace)
```

And outputting is as simple as a `print` statement:

```
print defang_word(sample)
```

So as you can see, the two versions look almost exactly the same.

Comment: @Justus, wouldn't `file(name).read()` leak file descriptors, since you never call close?